# OnDataChange method gets called and reports null object

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nullpointerexception

I have an application where I use `firebase` to store my data.

My data is retreived in a fragment using on `OnDataChange` method and I add data to my firebase in a separate activity.

The fragment as a alone entity to retrieve data works perfect. But when I add data in my activity immediately this fragment method gets called automatically and reports that `my object-> datasnapshotobject.child("column_name") is null.`

I have written a condition to check that if `datasnapshotobject.exists()` then only do further steps. Yet it bypasses all the above lines and directly jumps to `datasnapshotobject.child("column_name")` is null giving error. How can I resolve this?

**Code for retrieving data**:

```
 Firebase mref=new Firebase("https://robocon-89a7c.firebaseio.com/Competitions/");
mref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    for(DataSnapshot dsp:dataSnapshot.getChildren() )
    {
            if(dsp.exists() && dsp.child("city").getValue(String.class).equalsIgnoreCase("Pune"))
            {
                String start_date=dsp.child("start_date").getValue(String.class);
                SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");


                try {
                    Date chkDate = curFormater.parse(start_date);
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    String date1 = cal.get(Calendar.DATE)+"-"+(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) +"-"+cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

                    Date currentDate = curFormater.parse(date1);

                    if(chkDate.compareTo(currentDate)>=0){
                        myList.add("\n"+dsp.child("competitionName").getValue(String.class)+"\n"+dsp.child("institutionName").getValue(String.class)+"\n"+dsp.child("start_date").getValue(String.class)+" at "+dsp.child("start_time").getValue(String.class));


                        //System.out.println("The entered date is within the range of six months");
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("The entered date is before than the current system date");
                    }

                }
                catch (ParseException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }


    }
    String values[]=new String[myList.size()];
    values=myList.toArray(values);


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values);
    mylistView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mylistView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // value=dataSnapshot.child("city").getValue(String.class);
    //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"its "+value,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //chck.setText(ansList.get(0)+ansList.get(1)+ansList.get(2));
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

  }
});
```

Code to add data:

```
Firebase firebase=new Firebase("https://robocon-89a7c.firebaseio.com/Competitions/");
   Firebase mainEle=firebase.child(unid);
   Firebase firebasechild=mainEle.child("competitionName");
   firebasechild.setValue(competition);
   Firebase firebasechild2=mainEle.child("institutionName");
   firebasechild2.setValue(institutionN);
```

This way I add other column and data too, only provided some here.

Comment: check for "datasnapshot != null " instead of datasnapshot.isExist()

Comment: all possible ways like exists , !=null tried out that fragment was once executed and then we intent to go to activity to add data so it directly jumps to line that null object found.

Comment: Can you share your code here.

Comment: shared @MayurPatel as soon as data is added dsp.child("city").getV is null

Comment: There is no `datasnapshotobject.child("column_name")` in your code. Did you perhaps mean another check?

Comment: Actually there is the column named city which is only my column_name, I have 16 such columns so just uploaded code with initial 2 for simplicity

Answer (score 0):

I think your datasnapshot exists and really isn´t null, but nodes structure is diferent from  the method where you add data, so it doesn´t have the fields you´re looking for.

You wrote on database:

root

|-- something inside variable "unid"

|---- competitionName

|------ competition

|---- institutionName

|------ institution

And trying to retrieve:

root

|-- city

|-- start_date

|-- competitionName

If "city" or "start_date" are the value inside "unid" variable, no problem. But at least for competitionName you need to enter one node down.

Answer (score 0):

I have used  Firebase mref=new Firebase("https://robocon-89a7c.firebaseio.com/Competitions/");
So by children of this, I get uid that is main parent having all my columns mentioned so far.

I found the solution.
If your database is going to have new value each time and not going to change existing values please use **addListenerForSingleValueEvent** other than **addValueEventListener** because this will help us not listen for changes and will connect back only when attached again.

Now both requirements work independently as well as don't affect each others execution.